# Configure which gcc is called by shell script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I've been struggling with this issue for several weeks now, working it off and on.  I've got Ubuntu running on Windows.  I also installed OpenFOAM to analyze CFD simulations.  My issue is the default the gcc called at the command prompt is the OpenFOAM one.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (OpenFOAM) 6.3.0
```

I needed updated libraries installed for something else I'm working on.  I managed to get all the libraries installed, but linux is still looking to the OpenFOAM version of gcc (which doesn't see the libraries) when I run the program at the command prompt.  I am calling a shell scrip that in turns calls other programs, so I cannot determine a way to directly call out the full path to the desired gcc version.

I've worked out that the bash gcc command is actually linked to three versions of gcc:

```
$ type -a gcc
gcc is /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
gcc is /bin/gcc
```

This leads me to believe that the shell scrip is going to the first one and ignoring the next two.  How do I get it to go to the second?
i.e. so terminal would return

```
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
gcc is /bin/gcc
gcc is /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc
```

This should yield the correct version of gcc being called and the installed libraries I need to be referenced at runtime.

```
$ which gcc
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc
```

I was expecting this to return `/usr/bin/gcc` instead.

I tried appending the `/bin/gcc/` to the front of the path variable:

```
$ export PATH = /usr/bin/:$PATH
```

without success. (edited for syntax)

I also researched installing multiple versions of gcc on Ubuntu and worked out there is a command that should permit me to do what I'm trying to, but it doesn't work:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gcc
```

I was expecting to be able to select which version of gcc was called.

Comment: Wild guess: the OpenFOAM installation modified your `PATH`, and plonked itself before the pre-installed `gcc`'s `PATH`. Remedy: create a script that undoes that, use it in the shell that you'd like to recompile things using the system gcc in. As for setting the path, that won't work with spaces around the `=`.

Comment: Yeah, I had the syntax wrong on the PATH update.  You are correct, OpenFOAM updated $PATH, and did indeed put itself first.  But the way I modified the variable, it  put /usr/bin/gcc first up.  I would have expected that location to have taken priority.

Comment: If the original `gcc` comes first in the current PATH, but the shell still picks the OpenFOAM one you may need to tell bash to *rehash* ...  `hash -r` makes the cached PATHs go away. Spawning a new terminal or logging out and in again would do the same.

Comment: If you really typed `export PATH = /usr/bin/:$PATH` you should have gotten an error message. The correct command is `export PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH`. Shells are notoriously touchy about whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for rici's input:
$ export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH

prepended '/usr/bin' to the path variable before all the OpenFOAM stuff.

$ type -a $PATH
returned
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
gcc is /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
gcc is /bin/gcc

This should have resolved my issue except for some reason it's still looking for another library in the OpenFOAM directories.  As for the original question, the matter is resolved.